# How come it doesn't read the next line in the file?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to set the string to read a line out of a txt file which gives the location of the file to do its work with but for some reason it doesn't want to read the next line and keeps producing the same result which is the equivalent to line 0.

```
private void GetRaceNameButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string TestRaceNameFile = "g:\\Racing App\\RaceTestFile.s";
        string TestRaceNameFileUnknown = "g:\\Racing App\\RaceTestFileUnknown.s";

        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(TestRaceNameFile, string.Empty);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(TestRaceNameFileUnknown, string.Empty);
        var LinePosition2 = 0;
        String UpdateFileName = File.ReadLines(@"G:\\Racing App\\Update\\all.info").ElementAtOrDefault(LinePosition2);

        StreamReader sr;
        sr = new StreamReader(UpdateFileName);
        var set = sr.ReadToEnd();

        using (StreamReader su = File.OpenText(UpdateFileName))
        {
            string f = String.Empty;
            while ((f = su.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                var GetRace = new Regex(@"(?<=headline: "")(.*?)(?=""[,])").Matches(set);
                foreach (var Race in GetRace)
                {
                    string RaceToString = Race.ToString();

                    //Sweepstakes                        if (RaceToString.Contains("Sweepstakes") && !RaceToString.Contains("Juvenile") && !RaceToString.Contains("Mares") && !RaceToString.Contains("Apprentice") && !RaceToString.Contains("Amateur") && !RaceToString.Contains("Maiden") && !RaceToString.Contains("Fillies") && !RaceToString.Contains("INH") && !RaceToString.Contains("Beginners") && !RaceToString.Contains("Classified") && !RaceToString.Contains("Conditional") && !RaceToString.Contains("Conditioning") && !RaceToString.Contains("Conditions") && !RaceToString.Contains("National Hunt") && !RaceToString.Contains("Novices") && !RaceToString.Contains("Selling") && !RaceToString.Contains("Handicap") && !RaceToString.Contains("Intermediate") && !RaceToString.Contains("Hunter") && !RaceToString.Contains("Claiming") && !RaceToString.Contains("Hurdle") && !RaceToString.Contains(" Stakes") && !RaceToString.Contains("Chase") && !RaceToString.Contains("Flat"))
                    {
                        File.AppendAllText(TestRaceNameFile, RaceToString + Environment.NewLine);
                        File.AppendAllText(TestRaceNameFile, "Sweepstakes" + Environment.NewLine);
                        File.AppendAllText(TestRaceNameFile, Environment.NewLine);
                    }

                }

            LinePosition2++;
            Console.WriteLine(LinePosition2);
```

The `//Sweepstakes` tag is one of 222 as there are this many combinations so I have only shown 1.
As far as I know I think that's right but doesn't work.
The text file it searches through is like this

> g:\analyzer\ht4\1996\August\01-15\01-08-1996\goodwood\result\130988\equity-financial-collections-nursery-stakes-handicap.ht4

210000 lines+
 and it just adds the same 2 lines of text to the output file over and over and over again.

Is it something simple I am doing wrong or am I going about this all wrong?

Comment: Please reduce the code to only a snippet that illustrates the problem. Have you tried debugging this? Are you sure you aren't missing a `ReadLine` somewhere?

Comment: You keep rebuilding the very same regex but never apply it to anything? I'd bet your output is an empty line, followed by `SweepStakes\n\n` ?

Comment: @Rippo the curly brackets are unnecessary but they're not the cause of the problem. All they do is add an extra scope into the method, as such `RaceToString` isn't defined out side of them, but then it doesn't need to be.

Comment: its reading the first file but not moving on to the next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably apply the Regex object `GetRace` to the variable `f`, like this:

```
var matchesFound = GetRace.Matches(f);
```

and then base your `if`-statement on the contents of `matchesFound`.
See the **[MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7sf90t3(v=vs.110).aspx)**.

Also it is expensive and unneeded to create the `GetRace` Regex object over and over again. In .NET, Regex objects can safely be used multiple times. So it is best to place the line `var GetRace = new Regex(....);` before the while-loop.

Comment: so how do I implement that type of regex if I'm searching for text between the two identifiers?

Comment: Impossible to tell, without knowing what your lines (the content of variable `f`) may look like.

Answer (score 1):

Within the loop you apply the RegEx on `set` all the time, but that variable never changes.

In contrast `f` holds the content of the current line, but that variable will never be used within your loop.

Comment: what would I need to do, I don't understand this one?

Comment: I think you have to write `new Regex(@"(?<=headline: "")(.*?)(?=""[,])").Matches(f);` (and maybe create the regex only once outside the loop).